# setInterval() equivalent for python with custom event and non-blocking

Tags: javascript, python, multithreading, python-asyncio

I want to transform following snippet of my javascript code to python for ease of development with flask.

```
async function run() {
    // TODO: If isIngame is false then getTeamData, saveJson and exit the program otherwise getPlayerData 
    if (isIngame === false) {
        clearInterval(isIngame__id);
        await getTeamData();
        await saveJson();
        clearInterval(run__id);
        console.log("DONE");
        process.exit();
    } else {
        await getPlayerData();
        console.log("Running");
    }
}

isIngame__id = setInterval(() => {
    inGameStatus();
}, apiRequestPeriod);

run__id = setInterval(async() => {
    await run();
}, apiRequestPeriod);
```

Is there an efficient setInterval() equivalent of javascript where I can ping my API every 1 second at two different endpoints in a non-blocking manner? The custom event to stop these two events is `inIngame` becoming False.

Comment: AFAIK flask doesn't support async; you should use quart or another async-aware framework instead.

Comment: I don't need async with flask. I want the program to run asynchronously so that it can run both these tasks and still accomodate other added tasks.

Comment: In the question you write "for ease of development with flask", which I take to mean that you want to integrate async code (equivalent of the above JavaScript) into a flask code base. And now you say that you don't need async with flask. Python's async programming provides features very similar to the ones present in JavaScript, but it requires that the whole program is async from the ground up, which is just not the case with Flask.

Comment: This program generates output independent of flask. My question has nothing to ask about flask.